# "-[NSArray count] only defined for abstract class" exception when using an NSArray subclass

Tags: objective-c, sorting, cocoa, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSArray` subclass holding objects that I want to sort, but I get an exception with the message

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSArray count]: method only defined for abstract class.  Define -[CharacterArray count]!'

I've tried both below ways to do it but I got the above error both times.

```
[characters sortUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"strength" ascending:YES]]];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"strength" ascending:YES];
[characters sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

I tried some other ways to do it like below;

```
NSSortDescriptor *characterSort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"strength" ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)];

NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"strength"  ascending:YES];
NSMutableArray *arr = [[characters sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]]mutableCopy];

NSSortDescriptor *valueDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"strength" ascending:YES];
NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:valueDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray = [characters sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

but with these methods I get unused variable warning and nothing gets sorted in my original array when I call the method.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "character_array.h"
@implementation CharacterArray
 - (instancetype) init
{
self = [super init];
if (self)
    self.characters = [NSMutableArray array]; return self;
}
- (void) addCharacter: (Character *) charact
 {   NSLog(@"add character method entered");
[self.characters addObject: charact];
}
- (void) printAll
{
int num = 1;
NSLog(@"print all method entered");
for (Character *theCharacter in self.characters)
{    NSLog (@"%d : ", num++);
    [theCharacter printDetails];
}
}
@end

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "game_character.h"
@interface CharacterArray : NSMutableArray
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *characters;
- (void) addCharacter: (Character *) charact;
- (void) printAll;
@end
```

in main under import everything

```
CharacterArray *characters;
```

in main method

```
characters = [CharacterArray alloc];
characters = [characters init];
```

Comment: The error message suggests you've tried to subclass `NSArray` which, while possible, is not often needed or recommended. You should add the details of your class `CharacterArray`, and which variables have that type,  to your question so assist people in helping you.

Comment: @CRD I added the CharacterArray class and header. I had to use this type of array class for my assignment.

Comment: Why is `CharactersArray` inheriting from `NSMutableArray`, while all you seem to use that seems close to `NSMutableArray` is your property `characters`? Does make sense. You need to define `-(NSInteger)count` method, that may return `self.characters.count`, but again, that seems pointless to inherits from NSMutableArray.

Comment: @Larme I actually don't know why we have to create a CharactersArray class, this is my first objective c assignment. Its in the specification to use a class for it though. I could do it if I could make the array in main only.

Comment: @Larme I'm getting the same error then I try to use                          [characters removeObjectAtIndex:rand2]; I need to define removeObjectAtIndex in CharacterArray. How can I do that so I can remove specific index that are randomly picked

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that is having this error without using subclass, check if you are not using `[[NSArray new] initWith...]` instead of `[[NSArray alloc] initWith...]`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are required to create a `CharacterArray` class *and* that it should be a subclass of `NS(Mutable)Array`. Check that the intention is not that you should use an *instance* `characterArray` of `NS(Mutable)Array`, which seems most likely in a "first Objective-C assignment"; or that you are intended to write your class *without* inheriting from `NS(Mutable)Array`, less likely but possible.

Least likely is that you are meant to be learning that `NS(Mutable)Array` cannot be trivially subclassed. Note your error contains:

> ... only defined for abstract class ...

Objective-C does not really have "abstract" classes, but the system frameworks do use a design termed *class clusters* which can exhibit some of the same behaviour, and that is what the error message is trying to point out. With a class cluster simple inheritance does not work as expected as the public class, `NS(Mutable)Array` in this case, does not actually implement the behaviour of many of its methods but relies on other classes in the cluster to do so - and those implementations are *not* inherited by subclasses of the public class.

Sound complicated? That is why it is surprising it is in a "first assignment".

That said it is not hard to actually subclass `NS(Mutable)Array` provided you follow the rules, which are to implement a specified set of methods whose implementations are *not* inherited from `NS(Mutable)Array` when you subclass. Read the sections  "Subclassing Notes" in the [`NSMutableArray` documenatation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutablearray) and [`NSArray` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsarray) for the list of methods you must implement, which as the error message indicates includes `count`.

HTH